# RPM scriplet - execute the script on dependent application's running state

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I am creating the rpm package for 'appA' which is dependent on another application package 'appB', this dependency is handled through 'triggering' (considering appA will get installed only when appB is installed first).

Now below is my requirement:
 Is there any possible way to handle 'appA's' certain routine/script to be executed based on appB's status (say running, i.e. whenever appB gets fully started then only) as I don't want to ask appB to take care of my dependency/requirements.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "`Requires`" and "triggers" which are totally different things. But I'm pretty sure the answer to the question is no.

Comment: This does not make any sense at all. A package should be a singular independent unit. You are trying to take down those units. What you could do is.
Dependency by triggering is a borken idea. A dependency either is a dep or not. This has nothing to do with triggering.